# ckeditor cannot send the value

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

here are the code that suppose to use ckeditor to edit and send it to database, however, it doesn't work. anyone can help with this? code is working fine if take away ckeditor part.

Thanks again,

code for update database

```
window.onload = function() {
   $(".update_row_data").change(function() {
   action = $(this).closest('tr').data('action');
   form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input,select,textarea').serialize();
   console.log(form_data);

   $.ajax({
     data: {
       //Use that action name in ajax request.
       action: action,
       form_data: form_data,
     },
     url: 'updates_ok.php',
     type: 'post',
     beforeSend: function() {},
     success: function(data) {
       if (data == 1) {
         alert('update sucessful')
       }
     }
   });
 });
};
```

code for html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tbody id="_editable_table">
    <tr data-action="update_data">
      <td>
        <input name="country" size="6" style="border-style:none" type="text" class="update_row_data country" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="city" size="8" style="border-style:none" class="update_row_data city, data"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

code for ckeditor

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'data' );
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
     CKEDITOR.inline( elements[ i ],{
      height: 300,
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "upload.php",
        })
    //CKEDITOR.inline( elements[ i ], { /* config for this instance */ } );
}
});
```

Comment: do you get any respons from the server from your ajax ?

Comment: I have check dev tools, browser didn't send to server, seem cannot get the value, am I correct to set two class of this? class="update_row_data action, data"? it seems only recognize data..

Comment: I have check dev tools, browser didn't send to server - whats code error there ? look at network tab

Comment: sorry...but I only know if the code is working then updates_ok.php will display in network tab...

Comment: update_row_data on change is sending ajax who is sending request to the server, so on update_row_data change open dev tools -> network tab and see what is the code of the front or check the response if you still cant manage this give us a full link to updates_ok.php if is hoster on public domain not localhost

Comment: ckeditor.js:68 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
ckeditor.js:260 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 158ms-- is it that message?